# Error when trying to build Silverlight Unit Test (FW) with statlight

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, testing, teamcity

For two weeks now I get an Error-Message if I try to execute Silverlight Unit Tests via Statlight from console. I did not do any changes!

> Super Secret StatLight Code:
>   836D4425-DB59-48BB-BA7B-03AB20A57499
>
> Message is:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Fehler 0x1A88.
>   Debuggingressourcen-Zeichenfolgen sind
>   nicht verfügbar. Weitere Informationen
>   erhalen Sie unter
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60310.0&File=mscorrc.dll&Key=0x1A88

Executing the Silverlight Unit Tests via Statlight is a buildstep in my Teamcity CI-Server.

Unfortunately the quoted URL is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Statlight V 1.3.3981 instead of V 1.4.4147.

I got this Error only with the latest Version (beta) when calling:

```
C:\>statlight -x="*solution.xap*" -v=April2010 --teamcity
```

Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

whats the build step ? can you show us the command line call. I have got mine to work, but only without the -b option.